# How to get recommendations for PhD program when outside academia

Tags: phd, career-path

I'm looking into applying to another grad school to get another PhD, whether again in mathematics or a closely related subject. In assembling the application, where I should get recommendations from? I can't ask my advisor (I wouldn't be in this situation if he hadn't screwed me over the first time); and while there are certainly some other professors who remember me favorably, enough time has passed that I'm not sure they would have anything more than a desultory blurb to contribute. Math departments have little interest in recommendations from people in industry, and related subjects are presuambly similar. Is it possible to get some sort of recommendation or other bona fides available from industry that a PhD admissions committee in math, mathematical physics, etc. would care about?

Comment: What industry are you in? E.g. if you are in finance or a quant, you could probably apply to a stochastic calculus programme. If you are in cryptography, you have a good starting point for algebra/number theory, etc. Some places encourage "mature" students, and it may help to know a prof you'd like to work with, and perhaps try to contact them directly.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: I currently work as a general researcher at a tech company. Finding professors I want to work with isn't the problem; it's getting them to listen to someone random person off the street who already has a PhD in math but has been stuck in industry for several years.

Comment: Why another PhD? That seems unnecessary tbh. The point is you should know how to research, regardless of topic unless you're too far away from said topic.

Comment: I failed to see that you look for a 2nd PhD. I think that's what may scare them off. They will ask, why do you want a second PhD? Perhaps better to do a postdoc if you want to develop yourself. In some topics, a postdoc coming from industry may actually be more attractive as they know how to work, they have routine, discipline, and bring an orthogonal set of skills. Select a topic with some application angle, or where they may profit from links to industrial perspective, and you'll have a much better starting point than asking for a 2nd PhD opportunity.

Comment: anomaly's wish for a second PhD was covered in other question, [Getting rid of first degree to apply for second](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/63633/10220). The general reaction seemed to be against the whole idea of a repeat PhD, so references may not be the biggest problem.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: I want a second PhD because there isn't any opportunity for doing the theoretical math research I enjoy outside of academia, and I had a terrible advisor the first time around that prevented me from continuing in academia. If I could get some sort of pure math research position in industry, or a postdoc, or any other way of resolving the situation, I would. As it stands, I'm stuck with trying to get a second PhD as my best option. It's not a great option, but it's what I have available to me.

Comment: It could be worth refocusing the question (or asking a new one), since I think the second Ph.D. issue will be a much bigger obstacle than just coming from outside of academia.  Many departments simply won't accept an applicant who already has a Ph.D., no matter what the application looks like, and those that might consider it will be extremely skeptical.  The chances of admission will be essentially zero without extraordinarily persuasive letters.  So the key question isn't "how can I get letters from outside academia?" but rather "how can I assemble a compelling case for doing another Ph.D.?"

Comment: (In particular, there are various ways you could try to make academic contacts and acquire letters, but most of them are highly unlikely to lead to letters that would be useful for your particular goals.  It's not enough to acquire letters that attest to your talent or potential or accomplishments.  Instead, they have to very specifically make the case for why a second Ph.D. makes sense in your case, and that's a far more demanding requirement.)

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: That's fair, but almost all of the responses I've gotten to questions about getting a second PhD have been tangents about how I somehow don't or shouldn't want an academic career enough. I'd rather narrow down the question in hopes of getting a more useful reply.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: The reason for a second PhD in particular is that I claim that I would have been able to continue my career in academia if I hadn't gotten screwed over by my department. Since there's no opportunity to do pure math research outside of academia, I have no idea how to back up the claim that I have the interest in and talent for it to an admissions committee. But I really don't want to spend the next few decades writing code, compiling actuarial tables, or modeling the stock market, so I'm willing to give anything a shot.

Comment: _Since there's no opportunity to do pure math research outside of academia_ I am not sure this is true. [Yitang Zhang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitang_Zhang) did that. Some others did that. I don't think you need to be in academia physically to do that. If you are talking about experimental science, I would think you'll need other resources to do research, Pencil and papers should be enough for you to do pure math.

Comment: @scaaahu: Math does not work that way. (Also, do I really need to defend the merits of academia on academia.stackexchange?) I'm already very familiar with Yitang Zhang, since he invariably gets trotted out in this sort of discussion. One person has indeed managed to make it work, and good for him, but you might as well say that I can get rich by buying lottery tickets because a few dozen people have.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying. I made the above comment because what you were saying "Since there's no opportunity ..." sounds very absolute, so I had to counter it. I am in the similar situation. I am not really in academia, so I had a lot trouble, ranging from getting access to the papers behind pay wall to having no one to discuss my research, etc. I completely understand. But, I never give up. Frankly, I don't believe getting another PhD can solve your problem. I am not you. I may not know exactly what your problem is.

Comment: @scaaahu: No worries. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Getting recommendation letters should not be a problem, just go to your professors in undergraduate/graduate school, I am sure there will be many people who will happily help you. However, reaching them by e-mail could be somewhat hard, if you are not far away from school go directly to them and explain the situation(or perhaps a part of it). Moreover, there are many fields which require software skills, like machine learning, AI/neural networks,etc. Also, having a number of publications in conference proceedings or journal papers might be an alternative to strong letters.

Comment: Consider enrolling in a Masters applied math program. You can specifically mention your reason as being that you want to obtain marketable skills for job opportunities outside of academics. Then, with a Ph.D. in pure mathematics and an M.A. in applied mathematics (in which you want to do VERY well in, well beyond the minimal standards for the degree), you'll be in a much better position to find non-academic work. (Assuming that's what you want. You didn't say what your endgame was for the new Ph.D.)

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: Finding a non-academic job is easy; I already have one, and getting a master's degree in applied math wouldn't make me any more attractive to employers. I want an academic position.

Answer (score 1):

Who did write you the recommendation letters for the first PhD? Maybe you could use them again. I think there is nothing wrong in using recommendation letters from industry, in any case. I was in the industry when I started my PhD and I showed my boss' recommendation letter, but my field is not math but physics. 
On the other hand, I agree with people that recommend you to try a post-doc instead of a second PhD.